# Getting warning file permission with root user

Tags: software-installation, permissions, pip

What does this warning mean? I got it when executing following command using root at **amazon ec2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** instance:

```
$ pip install https://github.com/troeger/opensubmit/archive/0.6.2.tar.gz
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your question partly has an answer in the quote:

You are using `sudo` to gain root permissions, but the way you are using `sudo` does not adjust the value of `$HOME`, so **pip** tries to install into the pip directory of the user who invoked `sudo`.

This might cause problems if the actual user would want to remove or change the installed modules, therefore the warning.

To avoid the warning and unless you don't have to, use **pip** without root/sudo or invoke sudo as `sudo -H` which will set `$HOME` to the user you are changing to, in this case `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

This message hints at the fact that you might have executed pip earlier using sudo for the then-issued command.

For example

```
sudo pip install https://github.com/troeger/opensubmit/archive/0.6.2.tar.gz
```

Per default, sudo does not change the environment variable `HOME` and therefore `sudo env | grep HOME` is printing `HOME=/home/username`. Adding `-H` to the sudo command changes this behaviour and it prints `HOME=/root`.

To solve your problem you should make sure every folder in this path `/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http` (except / and /home) is owned by `ubuntu`:

```
sudo -H chown -R ubuntu: /home/ubuntu/.cache
```

Comment: The folders and subfolders seem to already be owned by the correct user.

The problem is the invocation of `sudo`, as the questioner mentioned he's using `root` to install.